# Analysing data with repeated measure variable

Tags: r

I have following type of repeated measures data (table 1), and events data in table 2 (single measure). I want to perform following tasks (in R or excel sheet please).

- To filter subjects who had any response at least 3 days.
- Response should be > 5 in each day.
- Then table 1 should have another column, date first response recorded.
- Then both tables should be merged

Table 1 – Response    Data

```
Sub_No    Response     Date
1          5          01-Jan
1          5          02-Jan
2          5          01-Jan
2          10         02-Jan
2          10         03-Jan
2          10         04-Jan
2          10         05-Jan
3          10         01-Jan
3          10         02-Jan
3          10         03-Jan
4          5          01-Jan
4          5          02-Jan
4          10         03-Jan
4          10         04-Jan
4          10         05-Jan
```

Table 2 – Event Data

```
Sub_No   Response        Date
1          No
2         Yes          30 Jan
3         Yes          29 Jan
4          No
```

Expected output/ result:

```
Sub_No   Event        Date Fist Response

2         Yes            01 Jan
3         Yes            01 Jan
4          No            01 Jan
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: We have no way to help if you post a messy question. Please read instruction and make your question clean and neat.

Comment: To be precise and clear, please post result table (calculated manually) for the sample data included

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, the data are not entirely clear. However, this may be helpful for you in getting started.

Assuming your tables 1 and 2 are `df1` and `df2`, you could try the following with `dplyr`. First, `group_by(Sub_No)` to look at each subject. With `filter` you can keep those that have at least 3 observations, and require all time points for `Response` to be >= 5.

Then, you can `summarise` since it appears you only need one final summary row for each subject, containing the first `Date`. An `inner_join` will merge with the second table (and include subjects if present in both tables). I included `select` since it appears you only want specific columns from the second table in the final result.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  group_by(Sub_No) %>%
  filter(n() >= 3, all(Response >= 5)) %>%
  summarise(Date_First_Response = first(Date)) %>%
  inner_join(df2 %>% select(Sub_No, Response))
```

**Output**

```
  Sub_No Date_First_Response Response
   <int> <chr>               <chr>   
1      2 01-Jan              Yes     
2      3 01-Jan              Yes     
3      4 01-Jan              No
```

Comment: Great, I will try this. Much appreciated your prompt help.